# Js jQuery bug? Can not detect element while hide() + slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, hide

I have a rare issue. May be is a bug of jQuery, I dont know how can I solve it.

While I am using below method to hover a element, meanwhile I was monitering the length of element.

**The problem** is the length of added element 'el' will return **0 while** using **hide() + slide**

```
hover(
  function() {
    if (!trigger.next('#id').length)    // if #id not exsist, add html
      el = trigger.after(html).next('#id') // el = new added html
    else
      el = trigger.next('#id')
    el.stop(true, true).show('slide', { direction, 'left' })  
  }, 
  function() { 
    el.hide('slide', { direction, 'left' }) 
});
```

If I switch to another method, **hide()**<-just hide, **animate(), fadeOut()**, all will return **1**.

The added html is existing. However, length will not return  **while hide() + slide,**

but **after finish hide() + slide**, will return **1**;

Please help to solve this issue.

**Issue** *is **el.length** will return 0 while hide() + slide even-though the el is existing*

Thank you very much for your advice.

I have created a example, **please check**.

> > http://jsfiddle.net/fantill/DFd7e/6/

Comment: There's no code in there that outputs, or returns, a length of anything...

Comment: I have made a example, please help to check

Comment: This line is odd : `if(trigger.next('#id').length)    // if #id not exsist, add html` it's the oposite, if that returns true id exists already.

Comment: @Till what are you trying to accomplish here..

Comment: i want to prevent the return of 0 cause adding new html when hover again

Comment: If you want to add a new element multiple times, you should not set an unique id on that element.

Comment: no, I do not want to add multiple times..

Comment: due to the bug I stated, I want to prevent adding multiples times...

Comment: What sets, or what is the value of, `el` in the second function? Also, please use semicolons and indent consistently--there's a "Tidy" button right on the jsfiddle page. Good indentation is good.

Comment: value is 1 always, but not while hide()+slide, please check my example, it appears clearly

Comment: `el` is not `1`. What sets `el`? Is it a global?!

Comment: please check my example...http://jsfiddle.net/fantill/DFd7e/6/

Comment: So it's a global? I believe simply answering the question would have been easier.

Comment: el is element??, not a global variable??

Comment: @Till Of course `el` is a global variable, and *references* an element.

Comment: I see, so what is the problem here? because the created el is not global, so not reading it? but why fadeOut or etc will reflect 1 but not hide() + slide

Comment: @Till ... No. What specific behavior is happening that you don't want to happen?

Comment: on my code, return 0 = add html...while hide()+slide is creating bug return 0 and it is adding html when hover again....there is not remove html on my code

Comment: It isn't for me; subsequent hovers are displaying `1` in div#C, so the code to add the HTML isn't running.

Comment: have you checked my example??....value will return 0 while hiding, after hiding return 1, thanks

Comment: @Till I'm running it right now, that's how come I said "It isn't for me, subsequent hovers are displaying `1` in div#C." The only way I can get it to break is by leaving the hover zone and re-entering while the animation is still in progress, because you don't handle that case.

Comment: I believe 'leaving the hover zone and re-entering while the animation is still in progress' is not a solution if you are using hide() + slide on hover event in my case....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're using **jQuery beta 2.0** ? It would have been worth mentioning.

You're also using jQuery UI which I doubt is compatible with jQuery 2.0.0b1.

I just changed jQuery to v1.9 and it seems to be working, I also added brackets and commas.

This is tidier :

```
if( !$('#B').length ) 
{
   el = $(this).after('<div id="B" style="display:none; width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#09F; ">YYYYYYYYY</div>').next('#B');
} 
else 
{
    el = $('#B');
}
```

Here's the fiddle updated :
http://jsfiddle.net/DFd7e/9/

EDIT: I enabled jQuery UI, and replaced this `$(this).next('#B').first().length` 
with this : `$('#B').length`.

`next()` doesn't work in your case because jQuery UI is adding a wrapper around the div that you're animating, you can see it if you open your dev tool.

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DFd7e/11/

Comment: thank you very much. the slide effect is not running.if not effect, that is just normal hide()..if normal hide(), value will return 1, my question is a solution if the slide effect is ruining.

Comment: Please re-check it if you enable UI